# all I need a projector that is like Xiaomi Laser but with Bigger Screen

Tags: projector

My friend recommended me this

https://www.tokopedia.com/tokobelakang/xiaomi-mi-ultra-short-laser-projector-5000-lumen-ansi-readystock-putih?gclid=Cj0KCQiAw5_fBRCSARIsAGodhk9iJ-vlMX_s4ZE_3u53Ca6Ozndew5HU5qpxiYhhHEJa470xELa8lvcaAky3EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Everything there is almost perfect.

5k lumen. Very short throw. I want distance to the wall to be at most 2 m. The smaller the better.

The thing is my wall is around 5m. Xiaomi laser can do 3.75 m (150 inch).

The throw doesn't have to be that short though I like it.

My only concern is screen size. Can I push this xiaomi laser to make a 5m diagonal screen instead?

Distance 2m is fine. So about .4 throw ratio.

Full HD. Higher better, but not if it's too much more expensive. Good contrast. If you have other criteria of what's good, let me know.

$5k max budget. But if I can get a very good one for $1500-$2000 I would need a good reason to shell out another $3k.

I know about projector central. Been looking for it. Still can't decide.

Oh ya, if possible, something popular enough that I can find it in tokopedia.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to start by saying that the throw ratio for this projector = 0.133 is very good.  If you put a different lens on it, for example that can focus when 70cm away, then your image would be 210" wide.  In other words, you can get a larger image size simply by moving the projector farther from the wall, provided you can find a lens that can focus that distance.  The projector you posted is very, very good.

The bad thing is, that projector lenses are actually what comprise the majority of the price.  For example, if you look through the examples below, it seems that the lens needed to project such a wide image so close, itself can easily cost $5000 or more.  Therefore, if you can purchase a lens to project a 150" image with such a low throw ratio, for such a low price -- I'd take it.

However, in case you are truly dedicated to getting a larger image, I will outline your choices.  I checked the projectors on Tocopedia, and the below projectors are not available there; however, all of the below projectors are sold by companies which Tocopedia carries, so I suspect you can get them easier than some other products.

Option #1: you can buy the NEC PX803UL with a NP39ML lens.  As [you can see](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwiHmIzE78_eAhVB3lMKHaD3DJ8QFjABegQIBxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nec-pj.com%2Fcat_data%2Fpj%2FWDPJ-1601-0012bN.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0K2NH1VC33N4tSchaQZt9u), this would result in an image of 100 - 350 inches, with a Throw ratio of 0.38 : 1.

Option #2: the Hitachi [HP-WU9750B](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwig1uOs_8_eAhVQ2FMKHe39AM4QFjACegQICBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fproj-support.maxell.co.jp%2FProd%2Fvims%2Fproj%2Fen%2Fprojector%2Fdocs%2FLP-WU9750B_Brochure.pdf&usg=AOvVaw03Olazc1ZhDtzgjn-uRPEO) or [LP-WU9100B](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=2ahUKEwig1uOs_8_eAhVQ2FMKHe39AM4QFjAFegQIBBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fproj-support.maxell.co.jp%2FProd%2Fvims%2Fproj%2Fen%2Fprojector%2Fdocs%2FLP-WU9100B_Brochure.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0vjESIgSmJfsk0JA0wJkQR), with a FL-920 lens.  Again, this would result a Throw ratio of approximately 0.327, and an image of 100 - 350 inches.

Option #3: In case you can have a little bit of leeway, and mount your projector 2.1m away instead of 2m away, there is the Hitachi [CP-SX12000](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=2ahUKEwig1uOs_8_eAhVQ2FMKHe39AM4QFjADegQICRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fproj-support.maxell.co.jp%2FProd%2Fvims%2Fproj%2Fen%2Fprojector%2Fcategories%2Fprofessional%2Fpdf%2Fcommon%2FCP-WX11000_SX12000_Brochure.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3ZbxaA8kURjm4UhHazFQRh) or [CP-X10000J](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwivz7TohdDeAhUG31MKHUXvCd4QFjABegQIBxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fproj-support.maxell.co.jp%2FProd%2Fvims%2Fproj%2Fservice%2Fpdf%2F10000_g.pdf&usg=AOvVaw01eab4vDKzYL-YVAJfAO4K) with the USL-801 lens.  Its Throw Ratio is 0.42, and it can project an image 40 - 700 inches.  This lens only costs $2500, which is pretty cheap, so it might be worth buying this lens first, and seeing whether you can retrofit it onto a cheaper projector.

The projector itself, although fairly expensive, actually has specs a little worse than the projector you posted.  For instance, for the SX12000 it's 1050x1400 pixels instead of 1920x1080, 2500:1 contrast ratio instead of 5000:1, etc.; the specs are even worse for the CP-X10000J.  But then again, the price of this projector is about half the price of #1 and #2.

Bottom line: I think that the projector you posted is very cheap, considering it has true HD, and such a high contrast ratio.  It is also about half the price of the last projector I posted, so is a good deal.  If you are willing to sacrifice image quality, and so much more money, in order to get a bigger image size, then projector #3 is your best choice.  But even then, I would buy the lens first, and only buy the projector if I cannot find a way to retrofit the lens onto a cheaper projector.  The first two projectors are great, but very expensive.

Comment: So, I can't just get larger picture by moving the projector backward.... Because then the lense don't focus. I will ask the seller directly

Comment: Yes, the lens is the reason it cannot focus.  If you get a better lens, then it can focus; but, not all projectors support better lenses.